# Can SharePoint WSS 3.0 Search Tiff's?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm having trouble finding links on how this is done.  I got PDF search feature to work, just not Tif's.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to configure the TIFF IFilter.

Here are the instructions.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd755985(WS.10).aspx

This assumes you are using Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7.  If that is not your OS then your best option is to purchase a 3rd party TIFF IFilter or upgrade your OS.

You can find information about 3rd party TIFF Ifilters here.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gayanpeiris/archive/2008/09/17/captaris-announces-general-availability-of-tiff-ifilter.aspx

Comment: But we are not using Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2.  I have a server farm with Server 2003 and server S008 Standard, and SQL server 2008 R1.